# Google Forms Custom Subject Line

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am new to Apps Script and I have found some great information on this site to automate an email with the form responses anytime someone submits a new Google Form Response.  However, I want the subject line to be the answers they submitted for questions "Last Name", "Employee Number", and "Business Unit". I've tried to modify a few different answers from other questions here and I haven't been able to get them to work. I really don't want to use an add-on as this will have employee information.  Below is the script I am using now.  It works great, but I just need a way to change the subject line.  Thank you all!

```
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  var currentTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(currentTriggers.length > 0)
    return;
  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
 
  var formResponse = e.response;

  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  var emailBody = "New form response:\n\n";

  itemResponses.forEach(function(itemResponse) {
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    emailBody += title + "\n" + response + "\n\n";
  });

  sendEmail(emailBody);
}

function sendEmail(emailBody)
 {
  MailApp.sendEmail("testemail@test.com", "subject", emailBody);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What have you tried to make the script do what you need? Also please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask] (in other words be more specific, include a link to the answers you have reviewed, but show what you tried). P.S. There is a missing `}` at the very end  of the code.

Comment: Hi Ruben. I tried the solution from the link below, but I couldn't seem to get it to send an email after I added the e.namedValues.  I also tried another method with just using the [1] and [2].  In regards to the missing } that is just due to my copy and paste here, but I do have it on my actual script. It is sending emails now, but as soon as I try to input any new script to make the subject line custom it doesn't work.  Any suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116534/how-can-i-set-the-var-subject-in-google-forms-script-editor-to-return-the-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  var currentTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(currentTriggers.length > 0)
    return;
  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
 
  var formResponse = e.response;

  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  var emailBody = "New form response:\n\n";
  let arr = []; 
  itemResponses.forEach(function(itemResponse) {
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    if(["Last Name", "Employee Number", "Business Unit"].indexOf(title)> -1){
       arr.push(response);
    }
    emailBody += title + "\n" + response + "\n\n";
  });
  // use arr, you can get your desired subject.
  const subject = arr.map(r=> r+'+');  
  sendEmail(emailBody,subject);
}

function sendEmail(emailBody,subject){
    MailApp.sendEmail("testemail@test.com", subject, emailBody);
  }
```

Comment: Liquidkat that did it!  I'll have to spend some time reviewing your solution to understand how it works. This was a huge help. Thank you!